# Return UserControl Value from method

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

control containing two text boxes now I want to get values from these textboxes from the page where I've called this inside my usercontrol

```
public string MethodHere()
    {
        return "Some Special text Which is only know to this User Control "+ FirstName.Text +" Last Name is "+ LastName.Text;
    }
```

The Page where I had called my user control I want to call this Method named "MethodHere" something like this

```
   UserControls_TestUserControl1 test1 = new UserControls_TestUserControl1();
        lbloutput.Text = "<br/>" +test1.MethodHere();
```

but as I call MethodHere it throws error on FirstName.Text saying Object Reference not set.

**Note:** I've to use this way of getting value from UserControl

I had already tried this also but this is not what I'm looking for

```
foreach (Control item in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (item.GetType().Name=="TextBox")
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)item;
                output+=" you Wrote: "+ txt.Text+" <br/>";
            }
        }
```

now the question arises why this code isn't suitable for me that's because I want to get Some Special text Which is only know to this User Control and I can get some thing back here.

Comment: Where are you initializing `FirstName` in your control?

Comment: that inside ascx file soemthing like this <td>
    First Name:
</td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="FirstName" />
</td>

Answer (score 0):

You can directly cast the textbox controls present in your usercontrol and use it's `Text` property like this:-

```
TextBox FirstName= (TextBox)this.UserControls_TestUserControl1ID.FindControl("FirstName");
TextBox LastName= (TextBox)this.UserControls_TestUserControl1ID.FindControl("LastName");
```

Then you can directly get the text:-

```
lbloutput.Text = "Some Special text Which is only know to this User Control " 
                  + FirstName.Text + "Last Name is" + LastName.Text;
```

**Update:**

If you want to call the method present in your UserControl, Assign an `ID` to the control when you define it in your mark-up  page:-

```
<UCL:TestUserControl ID="TestCtrl" runat="server" />
```

The, simply use this ID to call your method:-

```
lbloutput.Text = "<br/>" + TestCtrl.MethodHere();
```

Comment: bro! as I said "Some Special text Which is only know to this User Control" this is special text which is only known to it, I dont have it on my Page... I've multiple usercontrols and I've placed unique text on all these usercontrols that's why I'm trying to call method of usercontrol

Comment: I've done the same and got the same error of object reference not set

Comment: @Jahangeer - How come it's possible? Have you removed your code completely?